# How to send text within the Search field within multiple shadow-root (open) using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, shadow-dom, shadow-root

While yesterday I could easily navigate on archive.org with selenium, today I cannot use selenium functions on the website in any way. Even my code to click on a simple search button does not work. Is there any solution for this?

I used import undetected_chromedriver but it didn't work, I also tried playwright library alternative to selenium but it doesn't work.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

chrome_driver_path = "chromedriver"

keyword = "photo"
url_photo = f"https://archive.org/search?query={keyword}&and%5B%5D=mediatype%3A%22image%22"

chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
service = Service('chromedriver')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url_photo)
WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH
                                                             ,
                                                             "/html/body/app-root//main/div/router-slot/search-page//div/div[2]/collection-browser//div/div[3]/infinite-scroller//section/article[1]/tile-dispatcher//div/a/item-tile//div/div/div/image-block//div/item-image//div/img"))).click()
print("request successful")
```

Comment: There are a lot of shadow roots in that page. See [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73377520/webscraping-shadow-root) as a starting point, and forget about long, fragile XPATH locators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Search* field within the website https://archive.org/search?query=photo&and%5B%5D=mediatype%3A%22image%22 is located deep within multiple [**`#shadow-root (open)`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76613623/7429447) elements.

[image: search]

---

### Solution

To send a *character sequence* to the *Search* field you have to use [`shadowRoot.querySelector()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium/55763793#55763793) and you can use the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://archive.org/search?query=photo&and%5B%5D=mediatype%3A%22image%22")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('app-root').shadowRoot.querySelector('search-page').shadowRoot.querySelector('collection-search-input').shadowRoot.querySelector('ia-clearable-text-input').shadowRoot.querySelector('input#text-input')")))).send_keys("xtrabyte")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: xtrabyte]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to extract info within a #shadow-root (open) using Selenium Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65055114/7429447)
- [How to interact with Cookie pop within #shadow-root (open) using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71056513/7429447)

Comment: Sir, when I want to write a selenium script that will click on any image, I need to reach about 9 shadow root, I could not write this path. Is there an easier way to get this path or a tactic to write it?

Comment: @xtrabyte Yes, there are. Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.