# Cant find Element inside a Shadow DOM

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, button, click, shadow-dom

So im trying to click a button element, which is inside a Shadow DOM.

I use Python and  Selenium WebDriver. I also looked through the forum already and every solution which worked for others doesnt work for my problem.

I get this error: Selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".stack-card-footer"}

```
def get_web_element_from_dict_if_needed(driver: WebDriver, element_to_check_for_dict):
    if type(element_to_check_for_dict) is dict:
        first_element_value = list(element_to_check_for_dict.values())[0]
        element_to_check_for_dict = driver.create_web_element(element_id=first_element_value)
    return element_to_check_for_dict


def get_shadow_dom(element, driver):
    js = driver.execute_script
    shadow_dom = js("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element)
    return shadow_dom
```

```
root = browser.browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "file-stack-card")
shadow_dom1 = get_shadow_dom(root, browser.browser)

shadow_dom1 = get_web_element_from_dict_if_needed(browser.browser, shadow_dom1)

stack_card_footer = shadow_dom1.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "stack-card-footer")
icon_bar = stack_card_footer.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "icon-bar")
ion_buttons = icon_bar.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "ion-buttons")
ion_button = ion_buttons.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "ion-button.heart-outline")

shadow_dom2 = get_shadow_dom(ion_button, browser.browser)

button_element = shadow_dom2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button")
```

```
Elements Console Sources Network Performance Memory
Application
Security Lighthouse
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en" translate="no" class="plt-desktop md hydrated" mode="md">
    <head></head>
    <body class>
        <app-root class="hydrated">
        <ion-app class="md ion-page hydrated">
        <page-header-loading class="hydrated"></page-header-loading>
        <ion-router class="hydrated"></ion-router>
        <ion-nav id="main-nav" class="hydrated">
        #shadow-root (open)
        <page-frame class="ion-page hydrated" style="z-index: 99;">
        <file-stack-transfer class="hydrated"></file-stack-transfer>
        <ion-split-pane content-id="frame" class="footer-show md split-pane-md hydrated mobile">
        #shadow-root (open)
        <ion-menu class="split-pane-side md menu-type-overlay menu-enabled hydrated menu-side-end" role="navigation" aria-label="menu" content-id="frame" menu-id="accountMenu" side="end"></ion-menu>
        <ion-nav id="frame" class="split-pane-main menu-content menu-content-overlay hydrated">
        #shadow-root (open)
        <page-profile-detail class="ion-page hydrated ion-page-hidden" style="z-index: 100;" aria-hidden="true"></page-profile-detail>
        <page-file-stack-detail class="ion-page hydrated can-go-back" style="z-index: 101;">
        <ion-header mode="md" class="ion-no-border md header-md header-translucent header-collapse-none header-translucent-md hydrated" no-border role="banner"></ion-header>
        <ion-content class="md content-ltr hydrated" style="--offset-top: 0px; --offset-bottom: 0px;">
        #shadow-root (open)
        <div class="center-page">
        <file-stack-card class="flex hydrated">
            #shadow-root (open)
            <ion-item class="stack-card-header ion-no-margin ion-no-padding item md item-lines-none item-fill-none ion-focusable hydrated item-label"></ion-item>
            <slot name="additional">@</slot>
            <div class="content user-bar icon-bar"></div>
            <div class="stack-card-footer ion-no-margin ion-no-padding">
                <ion-chip class="views ion-color ion-color-transparent md ion-activatable hydrated" color="transparent"></ion-chip>
                <icon-bar class="icon-tool-bar action-bar hydrated" slot="end">
                    <ion-buttons slot="end" class="sc-ion-buttons-md-h sc-ion-buttons-md-s md hydrated">
                        <ion-button mode="md" class="chatbubble-outline e10941bb-5ca9-103a-1a9e-9a54dd780a2c md button button-small button-clear in-buttons button-has-icon-only ion-activatable ion-focusable hy drated" fill="clear" size="small"></ion-button>
                        <ion-button mode="md" class="heart-outline 24dd7bc8-6b99-786-1217-3e4ae919988e md button button-small button-clear in-buttons button-has-icon-only ion-activatable ion-focusable hydrate d" fill="clear" size="small">
                            #shadow-root (open)
                            <button type="button" class="button-native" part="native"></button> flex == $0 
                            <div></div>
                        </ion-button>
                    </ion-buttons>
                </icon-bar>
```

*Im expecting someone to explain me why the script cant find the element and help me to fix it.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with accessing Shadow DOM Tree with Python Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76326041/problem-with-accessing-shadow-dom-tree-with-python-selenium)

Comment: @I.sh. nope :/ i tried both methods already and they dont work for me

Comment: Share a link to that web site

Comment: @I.sh. is there any way i can send you that website in private? because you have to register to see the content and its something like onlyfans so i dont know if im allowed to put it here into the comment section

Comment: DM me on telegram @letsolve_it