# Select all shadow root elements of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, shadow-dom

I have these elements and I want to select all `sc-product-item` inside of each `sc-product-item-list`

```
<sc-product-item-list class="hydrated" id="selector-1>
 #shadow-root (open)
  <div class="product-item-list__wrapper">
   <section class="product-item-list" aria-label="Product list">
    <sc-product-item class="hydrated"></sc-product-item>
    <sc-product-item class="hydrated"></sc-product-item>
   </section>
  </div>
</sc-product-item-list>

<sc-product-item-list class="hydrated" id="selector-2>
 #shadow-root (open)
  <div class="product-item-list__wrapper">
   <section class="product-item-list" aria-label="Product list">
    <sc-product-item class="hydrated"></sc-product-item>
    <sc-product-item class="hydrated"></sc-product-item>
   </section>
  </div>
</sc-product-item-list>
```

I tried around a lot and it works for the first sc-product-item-list on the page but as soon as I try to use `querySelectorAll` for the list, I get an `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'querySelectorAll')`

```
<script>

var wrapper = document.querySelectorAll("sc-product-item-list");

var items = Array.from(wrapper.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("sc-product-item"));

jQuery(items).css("background-color", "red");

</script>
```

Comment: The person who closed this question knows nothing about ``shadowDOM``. The correct answer is to "Walk the DOM" and dive into each shadowDOM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71267809/how-to-select-element-tag-from-shadow-root

Comment: @freedomn-m `document.querySelectorAll("sc-product-item-list").shadowRoot` gives me a nodeList with all sc-product-item-lists. Now I want to select all product items inside of each element's shadow root.